# Save list data during a sharepoint deployment

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I have a sharepoint 2010 solution that is deploying a few lists that will be filled by the user. Each time I redeploy the solution, all the lists are cleared.

What is the best way to keep the data in the list ? Export them, deploy the solution, import them ?

thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your lists instances deployed by features try to use custom code in FeatureUpgrading method of Feature EventReceiver. This code should create backup copies of your lists (or simply rename it), copy all list items to newly created lists and delete backups.

Read more at

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/06/feature-upgrade-part-1-fundamentals.html